# COM port read - Thread remains alive after timeout occurs

Tags: c++, c, serial-port

I have a dll which includes a function called ReadPort that reads data from serial COM port, written in c/c++. This function is called within an extra thread from another WINAPI function using the _beginthreadex. When COM port has data to be read, the worker thread returns the data, ends normaly, the calling thread closes the worker's thread handle and the dll works fine.

However, if ReadPort is called without data pending on the COM port, when timeout occurs then WaitForSingleObject returns WAIT_TIMEOUT but the worker thread never ends. As a result, virtual memory grows at about 1 MB every time, physical memory grows some KBs and the application that calls the dll becomes unstable. I also tryied to use TerminateThread() but i got the same results.

I have to admit that although i have enough developing experience, i am not familiar with c/c++. I did a lot of research before posting but unfortunately i didn't manage to solve my problem.

Does anyone have a clue on how could i solve this problem? However, I really want to stick to this kind of solution. Also, i want to mention that i think i can't use any global variables to use some kind of extra events, because each dll's functions may be called many times for every COM port.

I post some parts of my code below:

The Worker Thread:

```
unsigned int __stdcall ReadPort(void* readstr){

DWORD  dwError; int   rres;DWORD  dwCommModemStatus, dwBytesTransferred;
int ret;
char szBuff[64] = "";

ReadParams* params = (ReadParams*)readstr;

ret = SetCommMask(params->param2, EV_RXCHAR | EV_CTS | EV_DSR | EV_RLSD | EV_RING);
if (ret == 0)
{
    _endthreadex(0);
    return -1;
}
ret = WaitCommEvent(params->param2, &dwCommModemStatus, 0);
if (ret == 0)
{
    _endthreadex(0);
    return -2;
}
ret = SetCommMask(params->param2, EV_RXCHAR | EV_CTS | EV_DSR | EV_RLSD| EV_RING);
if (ret == 0)
{
    _endthreadex(0);
    return -3;
}

if (dwCommModemStatus & EV_RXCHAR||dwCommModemStatus & EV_RLSD)
{
    rres = ReadFile(params->param2, szBuff, 64, &dwBytesTransferred,NULL);
    if (rres == 0)
    {
        switch (dwError = GetLastError())
        {
            case ERROR_HANDLE_EOF:
            _endthreadex(0);
            return -4;
        }

        _endthreadex(0);
        return -5;
    }
    else
    {
        strcpy(params->param1,szBuff);
        _endthreadex(0);
        return 0;
    }
}
else
{
    _endthreadex(0);
    return 0;
}
_endthreadex(0);
return 0;}
```

The Calling Thread:

```
int WINAPI StartReadThread(HANDLE porthandle, HWND windowhandle){

HANDLE hThread;
unsigned threadID;
ReadParams readstr;
DWORD ret, ret2;

readstr.param2 = porthandle;

hThread = (HANDLE)_beginthreadex( NULL, 0, ReadPort, &readstr, 0, &threadID );
ret = WaitForSingleObject(hThread, 500);

if (ret == WAIT_OBJECT_0)
{
    CloseHandle(hThread);  
    if (readstr.param1 != NULL)
        // Send message to GUI
    return 0;
}
else if (ret == WAIT_TIMEOUT)
{
    ret2 = CloseHandle(hThread);
    return -1;
}
else
{
    ret2 = CloseHandle(hThread);
    if (ret2 == 0)
    return -2;
}}
```

Thank you in advance,

Sna.

Comment: Just a stylistic comment: your code is difficult to read because you repeat yourself so often. I would recommend apart from this question that you refactor so that you are calling functions and setting variables only one time for sections that call the functions with common argument values or set common variables to the same common value.

Comment: Thank you for your remarks. I think you are right, but first i tried to make this code work. If this works, then maybe i'll make some improvements to the style that it's written. However, i can understand that for some people, maybe this is annoying. Thanks anyway.

Comment: This is a structural problem, you really need to re-do this code.  Study overlapped I/O.  Or beg, borrow or steal this kind of code.

Comment: I have been studing an article with overlapped I/O already, since dear Edwin below answered me.Thanks.

Comment: Overlapped I/O helps with some problems, but serial ports have their own timeout mechanism which won't leave incomplete I/O requests lying around (`CancelIo` doesn't always work).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `WaitCommEvent`.  You can call `ReadFile` even when there is no data waiting.

Use `SetCommTimeouts` to make `ReadFile` itself timeout, instead of building a timeout on the inter-thread communications.

Comment: Disabling WaitCommEvent and setting the right values to COMMTIMEOUTS structure gave the correct results. From the COMMTIMEOUTS Documentation: "A value of MAXDWORD, combined with zero values for both the ReadTotalTimeoutConstant and ReadTotalTimeoutMultiplier members, specifies that the read operation is to return immediately with the bytes that have already been received, even if no bytes have been received."

Answer (score 1):

Change the delay in the `WaitForSingleObject` call to 5000 or 10000 and I bet your problem frequency goes way down.

Edwin's answer is also valid.  The spawned thread does not die because you closed the thread handle.

There is no guarantee that the `ReadPort` thread has even started by the time you are timing out.  Windows takes a LONG time to start a thread.

Here are some suggestions:

- You never check the return value of `beginthreadex`.  How do you know the thread started?
- Use whatever synchronization method with which you are comfortable to sync the `ReadPort` thread startup with `StartReadThread`.  It could be as simple as an integer flag that `ReadPort` sets to 1 when its ready to work.  Then the main thread can start its true waiting at that point.  Otherwise you'll never know short of using a debugger what's happening between the 2 threads.  Do not time out from the call to `WaitForSingleObject` in `StartReadThread` until your sync method indicates that `ReadPort` is working.
- You should not use `strcpy` to copy the bytes received from the serial port with `ReadFile`.  `ReadFile` tells you how many bytes it read.  Use that value and `memcpy` to fill the buffer.
- Look [here](http://GetCommTimeouts) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa909191.aspx) for info on how to have `ReadFile` time out so your reads are not indefinite.  Blocking forever on Windows is a recipe for disaster as it can cause zombie processes you cannot kill, among other problems.
- You communicate no status to `StartReadThread` about what happened in the `ReadPort` thread.  How do you know how many bytes `ReadPort` placed into `szBuff`?  To get the theads exit code, use [`GetExitCodeThread`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683190%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  Documented [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683190%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  Note that you cannot use [`GetExitCodeThread`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683190%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) if you've closed the thread handle.

Comment: Unfortunately, the call to `WaitCommEvent` makes `SetCommTimeouts` ineffective.  The `WaitCommEvent` call needs to be removed completely.

Comment: As dear Ben Voigt posted before, WaitCommEvent has to be removed and SetCommTimeouts must be called with the suitable parameters for my occasion. However, all of your remarks seem to have a point and i'll keep them in mind. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In your calling thread after a timeout you close the threadhandle. This will only stop you from using the handle. The worker thread however is still running. You should use a loop which waits again.

Comment: Hmm, you are right. But my purpose is to use this function in a timer from another application. So, if the thread does not end, and another one is called, then weird stuff will occur.

Comment: Use the ovelapped parameter on WaitCommEvent and wait on that for a limited time.

Comment: That will still leave the port busy, so not a very good idea.  `WaitCommEvent` is not needed for receiving data and not helpful.